# How to prove that O(Ng) | O(g)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, quotient-spaces

I have this exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Show that for all $Ng\in G/N$,
>   $$o(Ng)\mid o(g).$$

For now, without using the canonic homomorphism $\tau \left(g\right)=Ng$.

Sorry but don't have any directions or ideas, that's new for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is $N$ a *normal* subgroup of $G$?

Comment: You could prove the more general result that, for any group homomorphism $\sigma:G \to H$, we have $o(\sigma(g)) \vert o(g)$ (provided that the orders are finite).

Comment: Bernard, Hm, thank you for turning my attention, nothing said about N, but I guess it is, otherwise the quotient group isn't defined at all, but it does said that $Ng$ in it, so I think it is. Didn't looked at it at all, that's a thought.

Comment: Hm, now when I think again, I dont know if a have any other instruments, beside using that homomorphism to prove that.
Derek, can you explain to me why proving that is a proof for the orders of the elements of G and Ng. I mean, what is the correlation between orders of the homomorphism like that and the elements of each group ? How the proving the first implies on what I want to prove ?

Comment: Applying the result I mentioned with $\sigma = \tau$ gives the result you are trying to prove immediately. Then azimut's answer in the more general setting becomes $\sigma(g)^{o(g)} = \sigma(g^{o(g)}) = \sigma(1_G)=1_H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(Ng)^{\operatorname{ord}(g)} = Ng^{\operatorname{ord}(g)} = Ne = N$$

Comment: Look's very simple ) wow, silly me )

Comment: And in which cases it's actually equal ?

Comment: @Ilya.K. Iff $\langle g\rangle \cap N = \{e\}$.